# remember username and password using Persistent Store

Tags: blackberry

Dear friends please help me......and also share some code to remember username(EditField) and password(PasswordEditField) using check-box(CheckboxField) clicked...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentObject;
import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentStore;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.CheckboxField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.PasswordEditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;


public class LoginFormMainScreen extends MainScreen {

    Hashtable persistentHashtable;  
    CheckboxField checkboxField;    
    PersistentObject persistentObject;
    static final long KEY = 0x9df9f961bc6d6baL;
    PasswordEditField passwordField;
    EditField editField;
    ButtonField loginbutton;

    public LoginFormMainScreen() throws IOException {
        setTitle("Persistence Test");
        editField = new EditField("username:", "");
        add(editField);
        passwordField=new PasswordEditField("password:","");
        add(passwordField);

        checkboxField = new CheckboxField("Rememberme", false);
        add(checkboxField);
        add(new ButtonField("Login"));
        persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);

        if (persistentObject.getContents() == null) {
            persistentHashtable = new Hashtable();
            persistentObject.setContents(persistentHashtable);
        }
        else {
            persistentHashtable = (Hashtable)persistentObject.getContents();
        }

        if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("EditData")) {
            editField.setText((String)persistentHashtable.get("EditData"));
        }


    if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("BoolData")) {
            Boolean booleanObject = (Boolean)persistentHashtable.get("BoolData");
            checkboxField.setChecked(booleanObject.booleanValue());
             if(booleanObject.booleanValue()==true){
                 saveChecked();
             }
            }

    }


    public void saveChecked() throws IOException {
        persistentHashtable.put("", editField.getText());
        persistentHashtable.put("", passwordField.getText());
        persistentHashtable.put("BoolData", new Boolean(checkboxField.getChecked()));
        persistentObject.commit();
    }



}
```

List item

Comment: Please provide some details like what about your current code is not meeting your requirements?  What have you tried?  And so on...

Comment: When did the title change to RMS from PersitentSore?

Comment: OK, I see the other question was closed.

Comment: Dear Scott  i just wanna to remember the user-name and password when i check the check-box "remember me".please share me some code to remember the same using 1.EditField Username; 2.passwordField password;and there is a CheckbodField checkme;

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are putting username and password into the hash table with the blank key "", but trying to retrieve it using the key "EditData".

```
    static class PersistentHashtable extends Hashtable implements Persistable {
    }

    PersistentHashtable   persistentHashtable;

    public LoginFormMainScreen() throws IOException {

    ...
    if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("userName")) {
        editField.setText((String)persistentHashtable.get("userName"));
    }
    if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("password")) {
        password.setText((String)persistentHashtable.get("password"));
    }
    ...
}

public void saveChecked {
   persitentHashtable.put("userName", editField.getText());
   persitentHashtable.put("password", password.getText());
   persistentHashtable.put("BoolData", new Boolean(checkboxField.getChecked()));
   persistentObject.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ... but i need the solution to handle this situation

Comment: Richard, what are the other option to do this...please give me the code to remember user-name and password by checking the checkbook...

Comment: Richard , i do what ever you suggested ... but still i am not able to get the expected...pls do help.... please give me some code to do the same using RMS also...

Comment: Using RMS would requires object serialization and much more complex software.

Comment: I found a problem that I missed before, your pesistentHashtable is only a Hashtable which does not implement the Persistable interface. You need to use one of the Classes in the API that implements Persitable, or specialize your own Class extending Hashtable and implementing Persistable. This is all covered in the API documentation for PersistentObjects and the PersistentStore.